# reloading module, need to re-compile sub modules?

Tags: python

sorry, im sure this is asked a bunch, but i couldnt find it.

in myModule.py:

```
from myModule.subModule import myClass
```

i am working on myClass, and want to stay in my ipython session and test it. `reload(myModule)` doesnt re-compile myClass.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat your imports after reloading the "leafmost" submodule. E.g., given:

```
$ mkdir myModule
$ touch myModule/__init__.py
$ cat >myModule/subModule.py
class MyClass(object): kind='first'
```

and then

```
>>> from myModule.subModule import MyClass
>>> MyClass.kind
'first'
```

and in another terminal

```
$ cat >myModule/subModule.py
class MyClass(object): kind='second'
```

then...:

```
>>> import sys
>>> reload(sys.modules['myModule.subModule'])
<module 'myModule.subModule' from 'myModule/subModule.py'>
>>> from myModule.subModule import MyClass
>>> MyClass.kind
'second'
```

You need to go via `sys.modules` as you don't otherwise have a reference to the submodule, and then you need to repeat the `from`.

Life is much simpler if you accept the wise advice of always importing a module, never stuff from INSIDE the module, of course - e.g., the Python session would be (with a change to the submodule before the reload):

```
>>> from myModule import subModule as sm
>>> sm.MyClass.kind
'first'
>>> reload(sm)
<module 'myModule.subModule' from 'myModule/subModule.py'>
>>> sm.MyClass.kind
'second'
```

If you get into the habit of using qualified names such as `sm.MyClass` instead of only the barename `MyClass`, your life will be simpler in many respects (easier reloading is just one of them;-).

Comment: my class's dont have attribute kind. maybe a python 3.0 thing (i have 2.6.4). either way, i followed your advice on using qualified names for  submodules and everything is working. 
thanks a lot. i also love your python cookbook book. 
alex

Comment: @alex, I'm defining an attribute just so as to make it simplest and easiest to verify which version of a class is getting loaded -- nothing special about the attribute's name and value, just an example.